# Can we merge both these tags, [fab] and [floating-action-button]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both the tags [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) and [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button) are used for [**`FloatingActionButton`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton)

- [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab)

  Floating action buttons or FAB are used for a special type of promoted action. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and the transferring anchor point.
- [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button)

  Floating action buttons are a special case of promoted actions. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI and have special motion behaviors, related to morphing, launching, and its transferring anchor point

I propose merging the tags [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) and [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button), because *both* the tags are used for questions related to `FloatingActionButton`.

Questions tagged [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab):    331 questions

Questions tagged [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button):      966 questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button) as the master as it was certainly more clear that [tab:fab]. At the end of the merge, [fab] was removed from 331 questions and [floating-action-button] was added to 278 questions, and a synonym was created.

This is the tag wiki of [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab), in case it is needed in the future:

> **About** 
>  The fab tag belongs to [Android-development](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info), it is used for questions regarding the [FloatingActionButton](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-floating-action-button) design
>   introduced by Google with Android 5.0

Comment: I found another similar tag [android-fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fab?sort=newest&pageSize=50) for **`FloatingActionButton`**

Comment: Synonymized that to [floating-action-button] as well.